# PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for FileQueryPlugin

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2.3.9.  I'm trying to call a plugin 'FileQueryPlugin' from a view helper using dependency injection.

I tried changing 'plugins' to 'controller_plugins' in module.config.php, but I got a variation of the same error message.

Here is module.config.php

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables'=> array(
        'MenuBuildLink' => 'qatools\View\Helper\MenuBuildLink',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'FileQuery' => function ($container, $requestedName) {
            return new \qatools\View\Helper\FileQuery($container->getServiceLocator()->get(\Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::class)->get('FileQueryPlugin'));
        },
    ),
),
'plugins' => array(
    'invokables'=> array(
        'FileQueryPlugin' => 'qatools\Plugins\FileQueryPlugin'
    ),
),
```

Here is FileQueryPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace qatools\Plugins;

namespace Zend\View;

use Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ConfigInterface;

class FileQueryPlugin extends AbstractPluginManager {

    public function fileQuery($filename) {
        $fileQuery = $this->getServiceLocator->get('qatools\Model\GroupFilesTable');
        $modified = $fileQuery->getModifiedBy($filename);

        return $modified;
    }

    public function validatePlugin($plugin) {

    }
}
?>
```

I'm seeing the following error message.

Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

File:

```
/mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:550
```

Message:

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for FileQueryPlugin
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('FileQueryPlugin', true)
#1 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/PluginManager.php(82): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('FileQueryPlugin', Array, true)
#2 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/module/qatools/config/module.config.php(405): Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager->get('FileQueryPlugin')
#3 [internal function]: qatools\Module->{closure}(Object(Zend\View\HelperPluginManager), 'filequery', 'FileQuery')
#4 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(923): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\View\HelperPluginManager), 'filequery', 'FileQuery')
#5 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(259): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'filequery', 'FileQuery')
#6 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(217): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'filequery', 'FileQuery')
#7 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(633): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromFactory('filequery', 'FileQuery')
#8 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(593): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('FileQuery', 'filequery')
#9 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(525): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#10 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('FileQuery', true)
#11 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(377): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('FileQuery', NULL)
#12 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(396): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('FileQuery')
#13 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/module/qatools/view/partials/job-wizard.phtml(4740): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('FileQuery', Array)
#14 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(506): include('/mnt/c/git-repo...')
#15 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Partial.php(61): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(NULL, NULL)
#16 [internal function]: Zend\View\Helper\Partial->__invoke('partials/job-wi...')
#17 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(399): call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\View\Helper\Partial), Array)
#18 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/module/qatools/view/qatools/jobs/index.phtml(1064): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('partial', Array)
#19 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(506): include('/mnt/c/git-repo...')
#20 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(NULL)
#21 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#22 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#23 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(103): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#24 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#25 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#26 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#27 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(352): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#28 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(327): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#29 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/public/index.php(22): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#30 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inconsistencies in your naming.

Your factory function is calling following:

```
return new \qatools\View\Helper\FileQuery(...);
```

While your classname is `FileQueryPlugin`.

You should rename the class or call `new \qatools\View\Helper\FileQueryPlugin(...);`

### UPDATE

You have two namespace declarations in your  `FileQueryPlugin.php` file you need to remove the lower one, and the upper one should correspond with the one you call in your factory (`\qatools\View\Helper\FileQueryPlugin`:

```
namespace qatools\Plugins; // <--- update this so it corresponds

namespace Zend\View;  // <--- remove this one
```

You should also make sure the folder where the file resides corresponds to the path `\qatools\View\Helper\FileQuery`, so the folder tree should look like this:

```
- qatools
   - View 
     - Helper
       - FileQueryPlugin.php
```

Comment: @matt_griswold If my answer solved your problem, please be so kind to accept the answer. By accepting the answer the question is also closed showing others that the issue was resolved.

Comment: I commented earlier than this fixed the issue.  However I was getting a different error briefly which made me think that the original issue was fixed, but the other issue was unrelated and the original problem and error is still happening.

Comment: Taking out the extra namespace worked.  Thank you for the answer.